# Can I use css-grid to display this layout?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

Can I use css-grid to display this layout?( as the image shows )

[image]

1 items is **unknown** number

2 spreading items over **four** columns.

thank -_-

Comment: You could use both grid and flex.

Comment: Flexbox would require a fixed height and Css-grid a defined number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the three properties to have the required results: `grid` `flex` `column`.

**I have shown demo with the last two properties `flex` `column` , you can achieve the same with `grid`**

Here used the `column-count` property as you want `4` columns so entered the value 4 . `column-gap` is property for gap between the coulmns .

[Read here to know more about multiple columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
.container {
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 40px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>
```

With the use of `display: flex` like in below snippet :

[link to know more about `display: flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

> Use media queries for different screen sizes

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap/*whether row should wrap or not*/;
  justify-content: center;/*to center align all the containers*/
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;/*specifies the height of a line*/
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no that doesn't work, as soon as you add more divs, things just get confusing

Comment: @AdarshDubey if you need more info or something confuses you in the above code feel free to comment any query

Comment: as soon as I add another div, it gets added in the centre, while we want to add it in the first column

Comment: That is because `justify-content` value is `center` . You can remove that if wanted

Comment: @AdarshDubey added an another answer also see , if it helps you

Answer (score -1):

Yep, there you go.

You can **definitely** do it with `grid`, the only catch is, you have to add the height of `grid-item`, and you will have a beautiful layout.

Like below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

Add as many as `grid-item`s you want, and it will work perfectly fine.

The only thing I'm unsure about is how you numbered your divs in the image. It's not possible (*at least for this code*) to do it that way.